# How can I check if a s3path exists or not in Spark [using scala]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, emr

I'm looking for a cleaner way to check if a s3path is empty or not.

My current code looks like this,

```
 if (!s3Path.isEmpty) {
  try {
    var rdd = sc.textFile(s3Path)
    rdd.partitions.size
  } catch {
    case _: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException =>
      (sc.parallelize(List()))
  }
}
```

I want to do it without creating an RDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check s3path and see if its valid then I pass it to Spark to create RDD like below

```
 public boolean checkIfS3PathsValid(String bucketName, String key)
{

    try{
        ObjectListing list = s3.listObjects(bucketName,key);
        List<S3ObjectSummary> objectInfoList = list.getObjectSummaries();

        if(objectInfoList.size()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

here s3 is **com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3**
and you initialise it by

```
s3=AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials("path of your s3 credential file"));
```

So in you code call the checkIfS3PathsValid and see if it return true. If Yes , then only you create RDD using sc.textfile other wise you ignore that s3path.

Comment: I don't think there is a way using wildcards to do this. Can you confirm. I am just trying to check if a prefix exists, but don't want to loop over all keys, which is what we usually do to get all common prefixes.

Comment: @RaghvendraSingh are you able to determine a single filename under the common prefix? Assume you generate files in parts sequentially numbered, like, prefix-00000 always exists as long as there is data, you can use getObjectMetadata method to obtain meta data for that file, if there is exception, the file does not exist hence the prefix does not exist. 

If you cant, there is a setting in list request called maxSize, you can set it to 1 to get only 1 key so you dont have to "loop over all keys", works the same.